# React sort element in the props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, logic, react-props

I have a parent component something like:

```
const MainComponent = ({ cluster }: Props) =>{
   // lot of other code.
   
   return (<DetailComponent cluster={cluster} 
                onRowBlur={handleRowBlur}
                onRowChange={handleRowChange}
                columns={columns} /> )

};
```

Now cluster has a property called `rows`, which is actually sorted in the child, and is something like:

```
const DetailComponent = ({ cluster, onRowBlur, onRowChange, columns }: Props) => {
    const { favoriteRows } = useRowSettings(); // selector

    const sortedRows = useMemo(() => sortRowsFavoritesFirst(cluster.rows, favoriteRows), [cluster.rows, favoriteRows]);

    return (
        <table className="DetailComponent">
            <tbody>
                {sortedRows.map((row) => (
                    <DetailRow
                        key={row.rowId}
                        cluster={cluster}
                        row={row}
                        isFavorite={favoriteRows.includes(row.rowId)}
                        onRowBlur={onRowBlur}
                        onRowChange={onRowChange}
                        columns={columns}
                    />
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
};
```

Now, I need to have the `cluster.rows` be sorted in the parent component which is `MainComponent`. My problem is:

1. I don't want to mutate the prop `cluster` and sort the `rows` inside the `cluster` which is passed to `DetailComponent`.
2. I can sort the rows in the Parent and pass it as a separate property on `DetailComponent` as `sortedRows`. But I feel this is not good thing to do, as cluster already has the `rows` which is same data as `sortedRows`
3. I can sort the rows seperately in the Parent and child with the same code as done in child, like

   `const { favoriteRows } = useRowSettings(); // selector`

   `const sortedRows = useMemo(() => sortRowsFavoritesFirst(cluster.rows, favoriteRows), [cluster.rows, favoriteRows]);`

   But this is duplicating the code. Which I want to avoid.

So the problem, how should I handle this situation. Any clues or pointers would be helpfull.

Comment: So do you want a variable that can hold sorted value in the `MainComponent` without directly sort it in the `MainComponent`, or create duplicate code? Did you consider create a state variable like `[row, sortRow]` and pass the `sortRow` function down to `DetailComponent` ?

Comment: Yes, I think I mentioned in the above options, see above options (Second number).